# Network Block Device - Receive control failed (result -32) - Kernel 3.16.0-41

Tags: linux-kernel, openstack, qemu, kvm, network-block-device

When I connect to a Network Block Device (NBD) using `qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 /tmp/disk` and disconnect subsequently without any modifications via `qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0`, I get the following error in my `syslog`:

```
Jun 17 05:40:28 os-compute01 kernel: [49031.670805]  nbd0: p1
Jun 17 05:40:28 os-compute01 kernel: [49031.917155] block nbd0: NBD_DISCONNECT
Jun 17 05:40:28 os-compute01 kernel: [49031.917303] block nbd0: Receive control failed (result -32)
Jun 17 05:40:28 os-compute01 kernel: [49031.917502] block nbd0: queue cleared
```

The two commands succeed and have `exit code 0`. I am running an Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS on Kernel `3.16.0-41`. I have also tried Kernel `3.13.0-55` resulting in the same output. Actually I am not sure, if I have a problem or if the output is just misleading.

The use case can be easily reproduced. Can someone help me to clarify, wheter I have a problem on my machine or not. My `os-compute` nodes are compute nodes for the current OpenStack Kilo release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. When you disconnect, the kernel keeps reading until the connection is gone. That then produces that message. You can safely ignore it.